# Boolean operation on iPad goes wrong

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari, boolean

Considder this javascript code:

```
var condition=  (typeof ctrl.dataset == 'object') && (ctrl.dataset.agent>'');
if (ctrl.id=='list_scale') _LOG('1:',(typeof ctrl.dataset == 'object'),ctrl.dataset.agent>'',condition   )
```

Where - by the way - ctrl is a dom object. _LOG is my debug function that handles output to console and loging files.

Now as you can see condition is the result of part 1 AND part 2, so if those two are true, the condition variable should be true too.

The output on most devices in most browsers is *true*, *true* and *true* -but not on my iPad 2 in Safari. Safari gives *true*, *true* and *false*.

I am baffled...